# Does async Inference support auco-scale for GPU machine now? I would like to run model inference by GPU machine

Tags: asynchronous, gpu, inference

Does async Inference support auco-scale for GPU machine now? I would like to run model inference  by GPU machine. If possible, could you provide related test out notebook for GPU inference.

Many thanks

If possible, could you provide related test out notebook for GPU inference. Thank you